# Learn Unknown parameters from Input,output and Known parameters - Online training

Tags: machine-learning

I am new in Machine Learning field and I want to achieve one task using Machine Learning, but I am not sure how can I do that. Please help me, I am trying to do following task.

I have an external function (don't know its internal working) which accept input force ranging from 0 to 9.8 (it's gravity constant **g**) and it produces output percentage from 0%-100%. This percentage will apply to real object and depend on the physical environment, it will apply some force that could be different than the input force. My objective is to get applied force near to required force. The external function uses some parameters to come up with the percentage. Out of those parameters, some are constants and some are variables which changes according to the outside environment.

Using required force, actual gained force and constant parameters, I want to fine tune variable parameters.

**Consider following diagram for better explanation**
[image]

**-------More simplified-----**

In below table I have KF(Known constant features) UKF(unknown constant features). Using all data collected i.e. Input, output, and KF(known features) find value of X,Y,Z. These X,Y, Z will not change.

```
Input | KF1 | KF2 | KF3 |...| KF10 |UKF1|UKF2|UKF3  |...|UKF10| Output(achieve same value as Input)
0.1   | 5   | 10  | 0.5 |...| 80   |X   | Y  |  Z   |...| P   | 0.1
0.5   | 5   | 10  | 0.5 |...| 80   |X   | Y  |  Z   |...| P   | 0.5
2     | 5   | 10  | 0.5 |...| 80   |X   | Y  |  Z   |...| P   | 2
4     | 5   | 10  | 0.5 |...| 80   |X   | Y  |  Z   |...| P   | 4
.     | .   | .   | .   |...| .    |.   | .  |  Z   |...| .   | .
.     | .   | .   | .   |...| .    |.   | .  |  Z   |...| .   | .
.     | .   | .   | .   |...| .    |.   | .  |  Z   |...| .   | .
8     | 5   | 10  | 0.5 |...| 80   |X   | Y  |  Z   |...| P   | 8
```

Comment: Is it a feedback loop that will observe if the current force is just right and create additional / reduce force as required? If so, do you know your ideal / optimal force or is it unknown?

Comment: yes, it is feedback loop which compare required force vs gained force and fine tune trainable parameters

Comment: Generally, it looks like you could use any regressor for this. The interesting question is: Can you vary the required force and see what is the resulting percentage?

Comment: I can vary required force and get resulting percentage. I can also vary percentage. Based on difference between required force and gained force I can add offset to percentage so that next time it will adjust percentage before applying to object. But my task is fine tune trainable parameters so that I don't have to change percentage in function, it will automatically adapt outside environment and give me better percentage. Thanks